# GitLab 5.4: unable to create user

Tags: ruby, git, gitlab, bitnami

(Raised issue https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4659)

I got [GitLab](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq) 5.4 using [Bitnami Stack](http://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab) 5.4.0-0

In this version there's no way to create user without configuring mail server.
(In other words 5.4.0-0 is not ready to use out of box)

> Password A temporary password will be generated and sent to user.
> User will be forced to change it after first sign in

**Where to configure what mail server use for GitLab open source git server?**

UPDATE: [GitLab 5.4 Installation instruction](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/5-4-stable/doc/install/installation.md) doesn't mention how to configure connection to mail server, but just how to install Postfix

```
**Note:** In order to receive mail notifications, make sure to install a
mail server. By default, Debian is shipped with exim4 whereas Ubuntu
does not ship with one. The recommended mail server is postfix and you can install it with:

    sudo apt-get install -y postfix 

Then select 'Internet Site' and press enter to confirm the hostname.
```

UPDATE 2: Running `sudo apt-get install -y postfix` on Bitnami Ubuntu gets

> Package postfix is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'postfix' has no installation candidate

UPDATE 3: `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production` output

```
[33mSystem information[0m
System:     Debian wheezy/sid
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  no
Ruby Version:   1.9.3p448
Gem Version:    1.8.24
Bundler Version:1.3.5
Rake Version:   10.0.3

[33mGitLab information[0m
Version:    5.4.0
Revision:   94a814d
Directory:  /opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/htdocs
DB Adapter: mysql2
URL:        http://gitlab.funshion.com/gitlab
HTTP Clone URL: http://gitlab.funshion.com/gitlab/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@gitlab.funshion.com:some-project.git
Using LDAP: [32myes[0m
Using Omniauth: no

[33mGitLab Shell[0m
Version:    1.7.0
Repositories:   /opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/repositories/
Hooks:      /opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:        /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git
```

UPDATE 4: Actually user password can be set if to open the user page again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We suggest to configure the application to use an external SMTP mail server for sending the emails. If you are using a Cloud image there are limitations for sending emails from the instance itself https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request In any case, you can send emails from the application if you install "sendmail" in the machine.

There is a quick guide to know how to configure GitLab with GMail or any other email provider easily at http://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/BitNami_GitLab#How_to_configure_the_email_settings_of_GitLab.3f I hope it helps.

Comment: BitNami GitLab FAQ page has a lot of good Q&A, thank for sharing.